# How to get only the real part of a complex number?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code snippet, where the np.roots function will provide two complext numbers and one real number. I was able to extract the real root, however the output is always Complex. How can I change to only real number.

```
Cd = 0.88
coeff = [1, -3, (3+Cd**2), (Cd**2 - 1)]
roots = np.roots(coeff)
X = (roots[np.isreal(roots)]);
print (X)
```

The output is usually

```
[0.05944403+0.j]
```

However, how can I get only the following as output?

```
0.059444
```

The reason I am looking for that is, all my next calculations are also resulting complex numbers.

Comment: `np.real` seems to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `.real`.

```
Cd = 0.88
coeff = [1, -3, (3+Cd**2), (Cd**2 - 1)]
roots = np.roots(coeff)
X = (roots[np.isreal(roots)]);
print (X.real)
```

Also, consider `X.imag` for the imaginary part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .real to get the real part of a complex number

```
import numpy as np
Cd = 0.88
coeff = [1, -3, (3+Cd**2), (Cd**2 - 1)]
roots = np.roots(coeff)
X = (roots[np.isreal(roots)]);
print (X)
print (X.real) # print(X.imag)
```

additionally, python has .imag to get the imaginary part